# Fill DataBase with sample-data

Tags: php, yii

I'm new in Yii, and I'm just curious, what is the best way for filling database with sample-data?
For more detail, I'm searching for: 
some lib for creating sample texts/emails/user_names, etc.
some convenient way to fill DataBase with these data.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yii doesn't provide any functionality to populate database with sample or test data, but you can get number of links on google(popolate database with sample data). One of such is - [Sample data genereators](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/test-sample-data-generators/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create something like this, which is actioned in the admin area or when you hit a URL.

```
for($i = 0; $i<2000; $i++)
{
    $sheep = new Sheep(); 
    $sheep->name = 'Sheep no '.$i;
    $sheep->save();
}
```